# Which MCU scenes are from Ferris Bueller?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, deadpool, spider-man-homecoming

In the Deadpool movie,

> The very last scene at the end of the credits has Deadpool asking the audience why they are still in the theater, like Ferris Bueller did.

Similarly, during Spiderman Homecoming,

> Peter Parker ran through several suburban back yards, like Ferris Bueller did. One of the yards even had Ferris Bueller playing on a large screen television, just to reinforce the reference.

**Which other MCU movies contain scenes lifted from Ferris Bueller ?**  Is a particular writer, director, or other behind the scenes person responsible for the references?

Comment: Deadpool is not an MCU movie. I feel the two references are merely a coincidence.

Comment: Also, breaking the fourth wall is something Deadpool would do by himself, it doesn't necessarily need to be a reference to anything else on the part of the writers (although I agree the similarity is remarkable)

Comment: The Deadpool scene isn't just a normal fourth wall break; the scene is designed to look almost identical to the Ferris Bueller scene.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I can determine, those two movies didn't share any production staff, and there haven't been any other *overt* references to *Ferris Bueller's Day Off* in other Marvel, Sony, or Fox movies I can recall. The fact that two different superhero movies both reference the movie is merely a reflection of how popular and significant that movie was to the generation of people making movies now.

---

*Deadpool* is a Fox movie, in the X-Men universe, directed by Tim Miller and written by Rhett Reese and Paul Wernick. It was produced by the usual team at Fox - Simon Kinberg and Lauren Shuler Donner - plus Ryan Reynolds.

*Spider-Man: Homecoming* is a Sony/Marvel production, set in the MCU, directed by Jon Watts and written by a team of people, including Watts, Jonathan Goldstein, and John Francis Daley. It was produced by Kevin Feige from Marvel and Amy Pascal from Sony.

In Jon Watts case, the scene was included because he was specifically trying to recreate the teen movie vibe of John Hughes. Keep in mind, these are the movies that people of Watts's generation were watching when they were becoming interested in movies. As [Jon Watts](http://www.indiewire.com/2017/07/spider-man-homecoming-jon-watts-john-hughes-visual-effects-1201855275/) says:

> “Those were the movies we grew up on,” Watts said. “I remember that age and you’re just constantly screwing up. You don’t know what to do yet,  and you don’t know where you fit into the world.”

With *Deadpool*, the connection was made by the writers because the Deadpool shares a major character trait with Ferris, as [Reese explains](http://www.cinemablend.com/new/How-Deadpool-Came-Up-With-Brilliant-Ferris-Bueller-Reference-112777.html):

> Ferris Bueller is obviously famous for many things, one of them is breaking the fourth wall, so it just kind of clicked in my head, like, ‘What if Deadpool is in the robe, and he’s walking down the hallway.’

Comment: LA LA LA LA LA. .... LA dee dah.